# how to reset the value of ngModel if user clicks on cancel button

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

Sorry for the improper Question heading.
I am displaying customer address and I am providing edit feature to change customer addrress.
For that I am using ngModel like this:

```
<mat-label>Contact Sub Type: 
<input [(ngModel)]="element.contactSubType"
  (ngModelChange)="editContactFunction(element.contactId, element.referenceNumber,element.contactType,element.contactSubType)"/>
</mat-label>
```

Typescript Code:

```
editContactFunction(contactId, referenceNumber, contactType, contactSubType) {
    console.log(contactId, referenceNumber); // here I am getting the value 
    this.editContactId = contactId;
    this.editReferenceNumber = referenceNumber;
    this.editContacType = contactType;
    this.editContactSubType = contactSubType;
}
```

Now I click on edit button and change the value and click on save
If I click on save then changed value is displayed however suppose I change city from A to B and then click on cancel then still B is displayed.
How can I display A if user clicks on Cancel Button.

I understand I am doing double binding and as soon as I change value it gets binded to html and typescript.But how can I resolve this

Comment: Keep the old values inside a second variable, then when the user click on cancel set your ngModel variable with the old ones.

Comment: My address variable is an array so I cannot store all the address along with their address Id.It is one way of doing but I am hoping to avoid it and look for a better solution

Comment: I haven't used but I was going through data-* something called as data-attribute but I haven't used it before and moreover I don't know if it will actually work

Comment: @Ahmed did you use reactive form ?

Comment: Its not a form. I am getting data from backend which I am displaying using Input box